# Warum ändert "keine" den Fall?

Tags: declension, adjective-ending

1. Es gibt schnelle Lösungen.
2. Es gibt gute schnelle Lösungen.
3. Es gibt langsame Lösungen.
4. Es gibt keine schnelle*n* Lösungen.
5. Es gibt niemals schnelle Lösungen.
6. Es gibt null schnelle Lösungen.
7. Es gibt drei schnelle Lösungen.

Ich bin Muttersprachler und mein Sprachgefühl sagt mir, dass 4. schnelle*n* heißen muss, also mit n am Ende. Ist das richtig und wenn ja, woher kommt das? Warum ändert das "keine" den Fall? Anscheinend passiert das nicht nur bei dieser Konstellation mit "es gibt" sondern auch in anderen Kontexten:

1. Zwei schnelle Schweine saßen auf der Leine.
2. Keine schnellen Schweine saßen auf der Leine.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the linked question, because *kein* works differently grammatically when it negates a noun directly (e.g. *keine Lösung* = "not even one single solution") than when it negates a phrase (***mit** keinem anderen Fahrzeug* = "with this but not with any other vehicle" or *keine **schnellen** Lösungen* = "no fast solutions but slow solutions"). See my comment to the answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Kein* ändert nicht den Fall, sondern die [Deklinationsform](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjektiv#Beugung_(Flexion)). Adjektive können *schwach* oder *stark* dekliniert werden, je nachdem ob ihnen ein [Artikelwort](https://deutschegrammatik20.de/deutsche-grammatik-inhaltsverzeichnis/glossar-grammatik/grammatikglossar-artikelwort/) vorausgeht oder nicht. Für das Adjektiv [*schnell*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:schnell) zum Beispiel:

> - Es gibt *die schnellen* Lösungen.
>
>   (*schwach*, da *die* eine Artikelwort ist)
> - Es gibt *schnelle* Lösungen.
>
>   (*stark*, da kein Artikelwort davor steht)
> - Es gibt *gute schnelle* Lösungen.
>
>   (*stark*, da *gut* kein Artikelwort ist)

Der Fall ist aber derselbe, nämlich jeweils Akkusativ.

Das Indefinitpronomen [*kein*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/kein) zählt ebenfalls zu den Artikelwörtern, da es anstelle eines bestimmten oder unbestimmten Artikels stehen kann. Deshalb trägt das nachfolgende Adjektiv *schnell* die Endung der schwachen Deklination.

> - Es gibt *keine schnellen* Lösungen.

Zusatz: Das gilt bei *kein* nur für den Plural. Im Singular wird, wie @RalfJoerres richtig angemerkt hat, die *gemischte* Deklination verwendet.

Comment: Diese Antwort ist falsch. *Kein* ist sprachgeschichtlich entstanden aus *nicht* und *ein* (ahd. *nihein*, mhd. *nehein*). *Keine Lösung* ist also gleichbedeutend mit *nicht eine Lösung* und steht deshalb im Singular. –– *Keine schnellen Lösungen* bedeutet dagegen, dass es Lösungen gibt! Nämlich langsame. Deshalb steht es auch nicht im Singular, weil es nicht Lösungen insgesamt negiert, wie *keine (einzige) Lösung*, sondern nur eine Teilmenge der Gesamtmenge von Lösungen.

Comment: Die Darstellung in diesem Beitrag versucht, den üblichen, eher traditionelleren Betrachtungsweisen gerecht zu werden, die jedoch im Detail nicht konsequent sind. Die (attributive) Adjektivdeklination ist nur in der gesamten Nominalphrase erklärbar. Außerdem ist der Wortart-Status von _kein_ widersprüchlich definiert : Es wird als "Indefinitpronomen" bezeichnet, das "zu den Artikelwörtern zählt". Traditionelle Grammatiken sprechen da vom "Gebrauch als Begleiter". Richtig wäre: _Kein_ ist hier ausschließlich Artikelwort (Begleiter, Artikel, Determinant, determiner).

Comment: Der Terminus "gemischte Deklination" bezieht sich auf bestimmte Artikelwörter, bei denen nachfolgende Adjektive im Singular in einigen Kasus schwach und in anderen Kasus stark dekliniert werden. Das betrifft den unbestimmten Artikel _ein_, den Negativartikel _kein_ und die Possessivartikel _mein, dein, sein, ihr, unser, euer, ihr, Ihr_, bei denen im Nominativ maskulinum + neutrum sowie im Akkusativ neutrum ein nachfolgendes Adjektiv die "starke" Endung trägt, weil das Artikelwort in diesen Fällen keine Endung tragen kann; in den anderen Kasus hat das Adjektiv die "schwache" Form.

Answer (score 1):

In den germanischen Sprachen haben die Adjektive zwei verschiedene Gruppen von Endungen. Die erste Gruppe entspricht denen der Artikelwörter; man spricht von **starken** oder **pronominalen** Endungen. Zum Beispiel im Singular maskulin:

| Nom. | Akk. | Dat. | Gen. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dies**er** Mist | dies**en** Mist | dies**em** Mist | dies**es** Mists |
| groß**er** Mist | groß**en** Mist | groß**em** Mist | groß**en**<sup>1</sup> Mists |

Die zweite Gruppe von Endungen enstpricht denen der Substantive der n-Deklination; man spricht von *schwachen* Endungen. Wieder im Singular maskulin:

| Nom. | Akk. | Dat. | Gen. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| der Ochs*e* | den Ochs*en* | dem Ochs*en* | des Ochs*en* |
| der groß*e* | den groß*en* | dem groß*en* | des groß*en* |

Ursprünglich hatte der Gebrauch der verschiedenen Endungsgruppen mit Definitheit zu tun. Im Neuhochdeutschen ist die Verteilung dagegen formal geregelt. Wenn ein Artikelwort mit Endung vorhanden ist, sind die Adjektive *schwach*:

> manch**er** neu*e* Kunde
> mit ein**em** schlecht*en* Gewissen
> kein**e** schnell*en* Lösungen

In allen anderen Fällen **stark**:

> manch neu**er** Kunde
> mit schlecht**em** Gewissen
> solch schnell**e** Lösungen

Daß die schwache Adjektivendung *-en* unter den sieben Ausgangsbeispielen nur im vierten Satz steht, liegt also daran, daß nur dort ein Artikelwort mit Endung, *kein**e***, vorhanden ist. In allen anderen Beispielen gibt es kein Artikelwort, so daß das Adjektiv selber die starke Endung **-e** trägt.

---

1 Ursprünglich hatten die Adjektive im Gen. Sg. mask. und neut. die Endung **-es**. Die alte Endung ist in Wendungen bis ins 19. Jahrhundert erhalten: *Sei gutes Mutes!* ([Grimm](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Seite:Kinder_und_Hausm%C3%A4rchen_(Grimm)_1857_I_242.jpg), [Fontane](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Fontane,+Theodor/Erz%C3%A4hlungen/Schach+von+Wuthenow/8.+Kapitel.+Schach+und+Victoire); [DWB](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/mut) unter II. 3) e) δ)

Comment: Ich kenne diese Wendung nur als "Sei gut**en** Mutes!"

Comment: @Lakynion: So geht's mir auch, aber David bezeichnet "gutes Mutes" ja auch als "alten" Gebrauch "bis ins 19. Jahrhundert". Die Duden-Grammatik (Ausgabe 2016) stellt allgemein fest: Es "breitet sich im Genitiv des Maskulinums und des Neutrums der Artikelwörter (...) die Form _-en_ auf Kosten von _-es_ immer weiter aus. Der Prozess ist aber bis jetzt nicht ganz abgeschlossen." (S. 260 Rz 356) Beispiele dort:  _am Ersten diesen Monats, bei Menschen meinen Alters, er würdigte mich keinen Blickes_. Die Akzeptabilität solcher Phrasen wird von Muttersprachlern unterschiedlich beurteilt.

Answer (score 1):

Eine kleine Ergänzung:

Grund für die Frage wird die Verwechslung der Funktion der Endung *-en* sein. *-en* kann in vielen Kasus und sowohl im Singular als auch im Plural vorkommen, kann Pluralendung vieler Substantive sein (Dozent/en, Doktorand/en, Universität/en; Herz/en) und anderes mehr. Zwei Funktionen von *-en* sind sehr häufig:

> Akkusativ maskulinum Singular: ein**en** klein**en** Jungen
>
> Dativ Plural: mit sein**en** älter**en** Geschwistern

Das kann dazu führen, dass man die Endung *-en* fälschlicherweise als eine Kasusendung liest, im Plural dann als eine Dativendung.

Im Plural ist jedoch bei der sogenannten 'schwachen' Deklination der Adjektive die Endung **in allen Kasus *-en***

- Nom.: die kaputt**en** Autos
- Akk.: der kaputt**en** Autos
- Dat.: (mit) den kaputt**en** Autos
- Gen.: (wegen) der kaputt**en** Autos

Die schwache Adjektivdeklination wird dann benutzt, wenn es ein Artikelwort gibt, das bereits die Kasusendung hat.

Das heißt im Umkehrschluss: Wenn es kein Artikelwort gibt, oder wenn es keine Kasusendung trägt, wird ein zu derselben Nominalphrase gehörendes Adjektiv stark = mit Kasusendung dekliniert: siehe David Vogt.